# Почему SQLite блокируется при изменении данных?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Подключил к приложению flask sqlalchemy и SQLite. Проблема в том, что при выполенении изменения данных вида:

```
data = User.query.filter_by(username='name').first()
data.email = 'email@mail.ru'
data = User.query.filter_by(email='email@mail.ru').first()
```

Возникает исключение, которое говорит о том, что чтение невозможно, так как база данных блокируется. даже если сразу после изменения строк в таблице сделать `db.session.commit()` возникает то же самое исключение. Помогает `db.session.rollback()`, но повторая попытка не помогает. Остальные запросы на чтение проходят нормально. Работает БД на сервере. Что я делаю не так? Вот сама таблица:

```
from app import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    username= db.Column(db.String(20))
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %s>' % (self.username)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было делать `db.commit()` и делать его на сервере в самом коде, а не через интерпретатор по ssh